# What are you supposed to do for "pass 2" sections in LFS

Tags: linux, compiling, lfs, binutils

I'm trying to build an LFS system but I've hit a roadbloack, what am I supposed to do for the 2nd passes. I thought maybe I had to re-untar again then compile their but that didn't make a new directory, then I thought a build directory had to be made inside the existing folder but that doesn't work out either, then I tried building inside the existing build directory, then I made a build directory INSIDE the build directory but both did not help at all. I don't imagine I need to include code as I'm certain the processes I've used were incorrect. Any help would be very appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chapter 5.3, more precisely the second *Important* box, tells you to extract the package, go to the directory that was created by the extracting process, follow the instructions, go back to the parent directory and **delete the extracted sources**.

So yes, you have to untar again, since you deleted the extracted directory structure.

Most (all?) instructions ask you to make a `build` directory in the top of the extracted structure.

Comment: thanks, it turned out I didn't see the last line where it says delete the directory :)

Comment: It **is** rather complicated.